# Soap error in Magento (Failed opening SoapClient.php)

Tags: api, magento, soap, installation, soap-client

I'm experiencing a problem with the SoapClient in Magento which leads to a not working external module.
The module is working on another Magento installation so I'm guessing it’s related to my magento install.

In my magento log I see the following errors:

```
2012-07-09T16:52:40+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(SoapClient.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2012-07-09T16:52:40+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(SoapClient.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2012-07-09T16:52:40+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening ‘SoapClient.php’ for inclusion (include_path=’/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/app/code/local:/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/app/code/community:/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/app/code/core:/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/lib:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php’) in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

I’ve searched this forum and google and found out that it had something to do with the open_basedir restriction. I’ve followed all instructions related to those topics but I’m still having the errors above.

Can somebody help out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if SOAP/PEAR PHP extension is installed on your server.
(on Debian/Ubuntu these are the packages `php-pear php-soap`)

Please check this post for solving issue

http://nickescobedo.com/583/soapclient-error-after-enabling-fedex-shipping-method-on-magento-ecommerce-solution

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/263573/#t403847

Comment: Please explain why these posts solve the problems, just in case the links break.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I just install soap extension via `sudo apt-get install php5.6-soap` and restart apache via `sudo service apache2 restart` and it's work well now.